# Else works even if "if" works

Tags: javascript, if-statement, sqlite

I'm getting value from SQLite3 database and put it to if-else, but for some reason and "if", and "else" works. My code:

```
// can_ask = 1 - user can ask
// can_ask = 0 - user cannot ask

// Getting user
db.each(`SELECT ${+msg.senderId} AS user_id, can_ask FROM users WHERE user_id = ${+msg.senderId}`, function(err, user) {

   if(user.can_ask == 1) {
      console.log("Works nice!");
      db.run(`REPLACE INTO users(user_id, can_ask) VALUES (${+user.id}, 0);`) // Making "can_ask" a 0.
  } else {console.log("You can't ask!")}
})
```

And if user can ask it returns:

`Works nice!
You can't ask!`

If cannot:

`You can't ask!
You can't ask!`

Why else is always true? How I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe you're getting two results from the query. But more importantly: you're vulnerable to SQL Injection. ***Always parameterise your SQL***.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `user.can_ask`?

Comment: most probably you get more results since you use `db.each` and not `db.run` or wahtever

Comment: @Teemu, i think no because the `db.each` already have fecthed the matching objects

Comment: @genhernandez returns 1 (or 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are getting more than one results from the query

Answer (score 1):

Do a **GROUP BY user_id** so you will only have one id of each row.